# Развернуть Cordova на iOS используя Visual Studio и iPhone

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, есть Windows на котором установлена Visual Studio и инструменты Cordova. Создал приложение для Android, и хочу теперь развернуть его для iOS. Есть в наличии iPhone, подскажите порядок действий. (В сети нормальный мануал так и не нашел). Спасибо :)

Comment: Для сборки все равно потребуется Mac ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: эх, не судьба значит, Спасибо.

Comment: Там вроде существуют сервисы, выдающие удаленный мак для таких целей в аренду

Comment: буду копать в эту сторону)

Comment: Граждане, кто влепил минус и "Непонятна суть вопроса"? Если вам она непонятна, это ещё не значит, что ее здесь нет. Вопрос более чем имеет право на существование и на него можно дать ответ